# Why can't $f(a) = f(b)$ in the intermediate value theorem.

Tags: calculus, analysis

In calculus class the intermediate value theorem was introduced as follows:

> If $f(x)$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$
>
> If $f(a) \not = f(b)$
>
> If $k \in [f(a),f(b)]$
>
> Then $\exists c \in [a,b], f(c) = k $

However, I do not see why it is necessary that the second condition hold, because it is true that if $k\in[f(a),f(a)]$ then there exist such a $c$, namely $a$.

(Note that this theorem was stated for the reals only, but I am comfortable with general metric spaces, if that helps..)

Comment: if $f(a)=f(b)$ then how'll you find $k$ between them?

Comment: Just to be sure, does your book have $\exists c \in [a,b]$ or $\exists c \in (a,b)$?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 My book has it in words, but it explicitly said inclusive.

Comment: I think you are right Juan in the sense that the constraint $f(a)\neq f(b)$ isn't necessary. However, when $f(a)=f(b)$ the conclusion is trivial so that's probably why they wanted to exclude it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask if it is true that given continuous $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ and $k$ lying between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, but not strictly between, then we can find $c\in[a,b]$ such that $f(c)=k$.

Yes, it is true. If $f(a)=f(b)$, then $k$ must be $f(a)$, because that is the only value lying between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, and hence we can take $c=a$. If $f(a)\ne f(b)$, then we can use the IVT.

Why is the IVT not usually stated that way? Well it is usually stated that we can find $c\in(a,b)$, rather than $c\in[a,b]$, so it would become false if we did not require strict inequalities as shown by Silynn. But you could state it the way you suggest. However, once one way has got well established it is usually confusing to start using a subtly different way.

Comment: +1 Do you know if there is a historical/mathematical reason that it is stated this way and not the way that I stated it?

Comment: I think the IVT was used initially to find zeros of unsolvable equations like $x^5 + x - 1 = 0$. You take an interval like $(0,1)$ where $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$ and so the IVT tells you that there's a zero in this interval.

Answer (score 1):

The Intermediate Value Theorem states:

> Consider an interval $I=[a,b]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and a continuous function $f:I \to \mathbb{R}$. Then there exists a number $c \in [a,b]$ such that $k:=f(c)$ is between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, that is, $$f(a) < k < f(b)  \text{ or }  f(a) > k > f(b).$$

If $f(a)=f(b)$, then it is impossible to place the value $f(c)$ between $f(a)=f(b)$, and expect to have either relation of $f(a) < k < f(b)$ or $f(a) > k > f(b)$ satisfied.

Comment: Yes, my question is why can't those inequalities be formed using $\leq$ or $\geq$?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is that usually the IVT is defined for open intervals.

On an open interval with $f(a)=f(b)$ continuity does not guarantee that you can find $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=f(a)$.

For a counterexample, consider $f(x)=x^2-1$ for $a=-1$ and $b=1$.

Comment: Is there a reason to use open intervals vs. closed ones? I know in analysis you use open $n$ balls, which might explain it (as I think the proof of the the IVT is done using the tools of analysis).

Comment: It's been a while for me, but the generalization requires the order topology, and you don't really talk about closed intervals with the order topology. At least that's how I understood it, someone might want to correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow $c$ to be in $[a,b]$, the result is trivially true: just let $c=a$. So the theorem should always be stated with an open interval in the conclusion: "$\exists c \in (a,b)$". Once you have this restriction on $c$, the theorem becomes false if you allow $f(a)=f(b)$ and $k \in [f(a), f(b)]$ (or even false if $f(a) \neq f(b)$, for that matter: requiring an open interval in the conclusion forces one in the hypothesis).

Comment: This seems circuitous to me, as if saying "the theorem is stated this way, so you must do this to state the theorem this way." Am I misinterpreting what you are saying?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring my first sentence: if you state the theorem using closed intervals, it's completely trivial. In that case, it doesn't even require the function to be continuous; it's essentially a tautology. Not worth calling it a theorem.